# How to match an array with multiple arrays and return the closest array

Tags: javascript, arrays, compare, match

I'm trying to make a drinks web application where the user enters ingredients and then return the name of the drink or cocktail.

My drinks array looks like this:

```
 // Drinks
 var drinks = new Array(
    [0,['Whisky on the Rocks'],['whisky','ice']],
    [1,['Vodka on the Rocks'],['vodka','ice']]
);
```

I have this so fare, but it is only returning the first element:

```
function compare(myDrink) {
var difference = [];
difference[0]  = [];
difference[0][0] = [];
var dCount = drinks.length;
for (x = 0;x < dCount; x++) { 
    jQuery.grep(drinks[x][2], function(el) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(el, myDrink) == -1){
             difference[x][0].push(el);
             difference[x][1] = difference[x][0].length;
        }
    });
    var theDrink = difference[x][0].join(',');
    if (theDrink == ''){
        return drinks[x][1];
    } else {
        var diff = 'The Difference is: ' + difference[x][1] + ' Missing: ' + theDrink;
        return diff;
    }

}
}
```

What am I doing wrong? And is there a better way to do it?

Thanks in advance,

Robert

Comment: Could you explain what your algorithm actually does?

Comment: FWIW, you may use the following structure instead: `var drinks = [{ name: "Whisky on the Rocks", ingredients: ["whisky", "ice"]}, ...];`.

Comment: @sp00m it searching the drinks array to find if the ingredients are there and if the ingredients match it returns the name of the drink else it returns the missing ingredient and the difference as an integer (so if you only have whisky it returns missing: ice and difference 1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I would do something like this: in your `for` loop, keep track of the minimum distance you've found and of its index:

```
....
var closest = -1;
var minDifference = 99;
for (x = 0;x < dCount; x++) {
    difference[x]  = [];
    difference[x][0] = [];
    difference[x][1] = 0;
    jQuery.grep(drinks[x][2], function(el) {
        if (jQuery.inArray(el, myDrink) == -1){
            difference[x][0].push(el);
            difference[x][1] = difference[x][0].length;
        }
    });
    if (difference[x][1] < minDifference) {
        minDifference = difference[x][1];
        closest = x;
    }
}
...
```

See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9dTWx/4/) for a full example. By the way, I strongly recommend using a more meaningful structure for the `drinks` and `difference` arrays, as suggested by VisioN, and maybe also making the function return some kind of data structure (closest drink index and ingredients array, for example) instead of a description string.

Comment: thank you for your answer. It's returning the vodka as missing when I add whisky and ice, but it should be returning the name. How can I fix that? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I checked the minDifference in the wrong place (should be outside the .grep(), when the values for that particular cocktail are all settled). I just updated my answer and the fiddle, which is here (http://jsfiddle.net/9dTWx/4/)

Comment: Thank you very much @Aioros! One more question, I'm trying to implement associated array like what VisioN suggested like so: "    var difference = [{index: 0,missing: ['test'],diff: 0}];", but I receive an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'push' of undefined" on this line "difference[x]['missing'].push(el);" which used to be "difference[x][0].push(el);"

Comment: You could do it like this: change the two lines `difference[x][0] = []` and `difference[x][1] = 0` with `difference[x]  = {"missing": [], "diff": 0};`. In this way you have a `difference` array, and at the x-th position you are inserting an object with an array property called `missing` and a numeric one called `diff`. Then you just replace every `difference[x][0]` with `difference[x]["missing"]` and `difference[x][1]` with `difference[x]["diff"]`. I hope this is not too confusing.

Comment: No, not confusing at all. :) And one final question (I know I must be super annoying). I added a screwdriver which is {index: 2,name: Screwdriver",items: ["vodka","ice","oj"]} so now I get the first array with a difference of 0 which is the "Vodka on the Rocks" drinks[1].

Comment: What I guess I'm looking for is a way to get a percentage of how similar the users input is to the cocktails then return the drink that is the most similar to the users input with out having extra ingredients

Comment: Well, the problem is that your algorithm only checks if you have all the recipe ingredients, and doesn't count extras as a difference. One way to solve this could be doing a second check in the opposite sense: instead of looking in the `drinks` array for something you don't have, this time you would look in `myDrink` for something that is not in `drinks[x]`. You could then add it to a new array property of `difference`, similar to `missing` (something like `extra` or `unnecessary`).